# Change 00:00:00:000 into total seconds in excel

Tags: excel, time, formatting, excel-2016

I have a column of time values in excel that are from exporting from another piece of software. The time is formatted as hh:mm:ss.sss (e.g. 00:00:02.147 -> 0 hrs, 0 min, 2 s and 0.147 ms).

I want to change this into total number of seconds in excel however any function performed on the cells results in a #VALUE! error. I have tried changing the cell type from General to Text to Time to Custom (i.e. [ss]) etc. however nothing has worked. Is there anyway I can do this? This also causes issues for plotting in python.

Comment: Are you trying to convert real time into a float that represents seconds with a decimal component?

Comment: Do you want to **drop** the millliseconds or **retain** them ??

Comment: Have you checked for other time questions on here that may already contain the answer you need?

Comment: It sounds like it may be text. Use `TIMEVALUE` in your formula to convert to time. It will return a value that is in days. Simple enough to convert to seconds.

Comment: OH! I hadn't even realised you wanted the entire time as a count of seconds until the dupes were added...

Answer (score 1):

The custom format of `"hh:mm:ss.000"` should do what you are after.

You can then narrow that down to `"ss.000"` and just use `=A1` or even just nab the seconds with `=SECOND(A1)` (if you wanted to do this long-hand then you can do a `=RIGHT(A1,6)` with a format of `"ss.000"` or even `=TEXT(A1,"ss.000")` / `=TEXT(RIGHT(A1,6),"ss.000")`.

The issue being that using `"ss.sss"`, excel is trying to append seconds on to time again rather than milliseconds, so if excel can first know the milliseconds exist you should be able to extract the seconds.

---

**EDIT**

If it's the total number of seconds you are after, multiply the DateTime value by the number of seconds in a day: `=A1*86400`

Comment: Won't this solution ignore what's behind the decimal point ?

Comment: @M.Douda not with the format of `"ss.000"` (the formula was just an example of obtaining the second from a DateTime format) a simple `=A1` formatted to `"ss.000"` should do the trick with milliseconds.

Comment: I think that all the OP is after is to get the number of seconds as you included in your edit.  Perhaps the main issue would then be that when you multiply a time by a number, Excel has a tendency to format the result in a time format rather than as a decimal.  The result needs to be either a general format or some numeric format.